# Creating SQL IN clause from delimited parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameter-passing

I have a parameter that has multiple items separated by semicolons.  I need to use these items in an IN clause.  For example:

> parItems = 'item1;;item2;;item3'

Then I need to add to a sql like this:

> SELECT somestuff, morestuff FROM sometable WHERE item in (parItems)

Is there an easy way to get this done?

I am sorry. It will be on Reporting Services looking at a MSSQL DB not a Oracle ODBC as I previously stated

Comment: is there a way to format the `parItems` first before feeding it to the sql statement? It would be easier that way.

Comment: SSRS supports multivalue parameters (specifically in IN clause)

Answer (score 1):

Just parse your string to replace the `;;` with `','` and you can pass that directly to the `IN ('...')` statement.

`'item1;;item2;;item3'` --> `'item1','item2','item3'`

The easiest way would be to convert your string before you pass it as a parameter.

Like this: `IN ('item1','item2','item3')`

Comment: I ended up using this.  I can't believe I missed the obvious!!  Thanks

Comment: the syntax for an IN clause in MS SQL is the same as in oracle:

`where column_name IN ('value1','value2','value3','value4')`

Check whether or not passing it to reporting services requires you to escape the quotes in a different way.

Comment: EplusL, if the parameter only had one item in it, it works fine.  Like WHERE Column_name in (item).  As soon as you add multiple items with or without the quotes it doesn't work.  I don't think SQL is treating it as just a string.

Comment: that's why you have to pass it as one string by escaping the quotes in there, then once it's passed you can just set it inside of your ()

Answer (score 1):

You can.  But you'll need a bit of infrastructure.

You'll need a collection type defined in SQL.  Assuming each item is no more than 100 bytes

```
CREATE TYPE item_arr
    AS TABLE OF varchar2(100);
```

You would then need a function that parses the semicolon-separated list and returns this collection type.  I would use a variant of Tom Kyte's [in_list function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425)

```
create or replace function in_list( p_items in varchar2 )
  return item_arr
as
  l_string varchar2(32000) := p_items || ';';
  l_items  item_arr := item_arr();
  l_pos    number;
begin
  loop
     exit when l_string is null;
     l_pos := instr( l_string, ';' );
     l_items.extend;
     l_items(l_items.count) :=
                 ltrim( rtrim( substr( l_string, 1, l_pos-1 ) ) );
     l_string := substr( l_string, l_pos+1 );
  end loop;
  return l_items;
end;
```

Then, you can use this function in your SQL statement

```
SELECT somestuff, morestuff 
  FROM sometable 
 WHERE item in (SELECT column_value
                  FROM TABLE( in_list( parItems )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another variation; similar to Justin's answer, but for SQL Server:

Below function will return a table, which can be joined on.

```
CREATE FUNCTION listToTable (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (item varchar(50) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(';', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (item)
         VALUES (convert(varchar, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   RETURN
END

SELECT somestuff, morestuff 
FROM sometable a
join listToTable('item1;item2;item3') b
on a.columnA = b.item
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if the list is relatively short (i.e. less than 4000 characters), is to use the INSTR function:

```
SELECT somestuff, morestuff FROM sometable
WHERE INSTR( ';;' || parItems || ';;'
           , ';;' || item || ';;'
           ) > 0;
```

The main downside to this approach, however, is that the predicate is not selective. This, however, is not always a problem depending on the amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use AsG
Go
Drop FUNCTION AsG_inListesiOlustur
Go
CREATE FUNCTION AsG_inListesiOlustur (@pDegerListesi nvarchar(MAX), @pBossaVarsayilanDeger varchar(50))
   RETURNS @pNeticeTablo TABLE (Deger varchar(50) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Pozisyon        int,
           @sonrakiPozisyon    int,
           @uzunluk   int

   SELECT @Pozisyon = 0, @sonrakiPozisyon = 1
   Select @pDegerListesi = LTRIM(RTRIM(@pDegerListesi))
   If LEN(@pDegerListesi) = 0
     Begin
     If LEN(@pBossaVarsayilanDeger) > 0 
       Begin
       INSERT @pNeticeTablo (Deger) VALUES (@pBossaVarsayilanDeger)
       End
     End Else
     Begin   
     WHILE @sonrakiPozisyon > 0
       BEGIN
       SELECT @sonrakiPozisyon = CharIndex(',', @pDegerListesi, @Pozisyon + 1)
       SELECT @uzunluk = CASE WHEN @sonrakiPozisyon > 0
                              THEN @sonrakiPozisyon
                              ELSE Len(@pDegerListesi) + 1
                         END - @Pozisyon - 1
       INSERT @pNeticeTablo (Deger)
          VALUES (Convert(varchar, SubString(@pDegerListesi, @Pozisyon + 1, @uzunluk)))
       SELECT @Pozisyon = @sonrakiPozisyon
       End
     End
   RETURN
END
Go

Select * From  [AsG].[dbo].[AsG_inListesiOlustur]('1,4', '0')
Go

Select * From  [AsG].[dbo].[AsG_inListesiOlustur]('', '')
Go
```